# Doctrine not creating one-to-many relationship on doctrine:schema:update

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities `User` and `Shout` using annotations in the respective classes. `User` can have many `shouts`. For some reason when I create the annotations and then run `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` it does not show the relationship and when I run the actual update, it creates the tables but does not create the relationships. Here are the classes:

```
/**
 * Shout
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shouts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShoutRepository")
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 */
class Shout
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="shouts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
     */
    private $message;
......

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shout", mappedBy="users")
     */
    private $shouts;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->shouts = new ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

... and the `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`

```
CREATE TABLE shouts (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, message LONGTEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE users (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, username_canonical VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email_canonical VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, enabled TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, salt VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_login DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, locked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, expired TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, expires_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, confirmation_token VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, password_requested_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, roles LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)', credentials_expired TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, credentials_expire_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E992FC23A8 (username_canonical), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E9A0D96FBF (email_canonical), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any old mapping files lurking under Resources/config/doctrine.

Comment: @Cerad It is a fairly fresh install of Symfony 3. I looked and am not finding anything like that.

Comment: I suppose it could be a cache problem but seems unlikely.  Try clearing it.  Sure seems like you have another mapping file which would interfere with your annotations.  Just for kicks, add another column to one of your entities and see if the update picks it up.

Comment: @Cerad I just created a column `test` for the `users` table and it did create it. I should note that the `BaseUser` that `User` is extending is from the FOSUserBundle (if that matters). Any other ideas?

Comment: @Cerad So.... It looks like the FOSUserBundle uses an XML mapping file in their vendor package. This is what populates the `User` table. However, I am still able to add extra columns and even change the table name using annotations, so what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotations you using are wrong, you should use `Column` OR `ManyToOne` but not both.

```
class Shout
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="shouts")
     */
    private $user;

    // ...
}

class User extends BaseUser
{

    // ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|Shout[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shout", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $shouts;

    // ...
}
```

**Note**:

The `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")` line is kind of useless as doctrine smart enough to figure out the column names and these are the default values. You should instead think about if the relationship is optional or not and use `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL", nullable=true)` or `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue and thanks for pointing out whether the relationship is optional or not. In my case, since a shout cannot reside without a user, I will `cascade` upon deletion.